# How to validate each array index in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

I have array indexes storing data through ajax call. I want to put validation on only one index in the array. Here is my code.

```
 foreach($request->info as $info){
                 
                    $order = new Shipment; 
                    $order->clientRef =$info[0]; 
                    $order->receiverName =$info[1];  //validate name only
                    $order->deliverAddress =$info[2];  
                    $order->save();
}
```

I need to validate only `$info[1];` as `required`

Array from front end as below

```
 array:1 [
  "info" => array:1 [
    0 => array:21 [
      0 => "123"
      1 => null
      2 => "xyz"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Try this `$validated = $request->validate([   "info.*.1"  => "required",`]);`

Comment: Not helpful....{message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {info.0.1: ["The info.0.1 field is required."]}}
errors: {info.0.1: ["The info.0.1 field is required."]}
info.0.1: ["The info.0.1 field is required."]
0: "The info.0.1 field is required."
message: "The given data was invalid."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    "info.*.1"  => "required"
]);
```